# How to left align in the page (not only in the cell) math expressions (written with latex) in markdown?

Tags: latex, markdown

Today, I'm able to left align mathematical expressions with `markdown` and `latex` :

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
& P(X = r) = \frac{1}{n} \\
& P(X \le r) = F(X) = \frac{r}{n} \\
& E(X) = \frac{n+1}{2} \\
& V(X) = \frac{n^2 - 1}{12}
\end{aligned}$$
```

or

```
\begin{align}
& P(X = r) = \frac{1}{n} \\
& P(X \le r) = F(X) = \frac{r}{n} \\
& E(X) = \frac{n+1}{2} \\
& V(X) = \frac{n^2 - 1}{12}
\end{align}
```

All the expressions are then left aligned, but they are still put at the center of the page :

```
I show you how to have 114 :
                         114 = 112 + 2
                         114 = 100 + 7 + 7
                         114 = 50 + 50 + 7 + 3 + 4
```

(by default `latex` does this formatting if you don't align :

```
I show you how to have 114 :
                              114 = 112 + 2
                            114 = 100 + 7 + 7
                        114 = 50 + 50 + 7 + 3 + 4
```

)

I do not want reader eyes having to go left to start reading an explanatory sentence, then at the center of the page to read a formula, then left again for the next sentence, and so on.

I would like my mathematical expressions to be also left aligned on the page. And have this :

```
I show you how to have 114 :
114 = 112 + 2
114 = 100 + 7 + 7
114 = 50 + 50 + 7 + 3 + 4
```

I **do not** want to use single **$** delimiters, `$ ... $` because they degrade mathematical formulas making them less readable.

Any summation depicts the differences : `$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2$$` and `$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2$` don't display the things with the same quality : in inline mode, `latex` "compress" in height all the elements the most it can to avoid making the line higher than it is.

Comment: Maybe you should use the fleqn option of amsmath if I understand properly what you want. `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`

Comment: Thanks, Alain. Putting the option `fleqn` in the header worked. If you attempt to redeclare `\usepackage{amsmath}`, `pandoc` will declare a conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alain, his solution works. Add to the metadata section of the markdown file the `classoption: fleqn`. Don't add the `\usepackage{amsmath}` with `pandoc` : it might cause a conflict. Only the classoption.

```
---
classoption: fleqn

title: "Statistiques et Spark"
author: Marc Le Bihan
geometry: margin=2cm
urlcolor: blue
---

$$
\begin{aligned}
& P(X = r) = \frac{1}{n} \\
& P(X \le r) = F(X) = \frac{r}{n} \\
& E(X) = \frac{n+1}{2} \\
& V(X) = \frac{n^2 - 1}{12}
\end{aligned}
$$
```

then works, or this alternative syntax can be used :

```
$$P(X = r) = \frac{1}{n}$$
$$P(X \le r) = F(X) = \frac{r}{n}$$
$$E(X) = \frac{n+1}{2}$$
$$V(X) = \frac{n^2 - 1}{12}$$
```

that adds a subtle spacing in between lines, who might please or not.